# Call method and reRender datatable on InputText change

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable

I'm learning some of JSF and I want know somethings. I already searched a lot in [Google](http://yes-i-searched-in-google.com), Stack Overflow and famous websites like [Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/) and I didn't find the solution.

Actually I have one **input text** and a DataTable in the same page. The code appears something like this:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="discipline" 
    value="#{disciplineMBean.name}" 
    valueChangeListener="#{disciplineMBean.updateList}">
       <f:ajax event="keyup" reRender="myTable"/>  
    </h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{disciplineMBean.create}">
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>

<h:form>
    <h:dataTable id="myTable" var="disciplina" 
    value="#{disciplinaMBean.disciplineList}">

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>       
            <h:outputText value="#{discipline.name}" />
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

**What I want is**: when the inputText value change, I want call the method "updateList", that will update the disciplineList with the matching disciplines (the connection with DB is `ok`). After that I want reRender "myTable" with the matched results - via Ajax, without page reload.

```
public void updateList(){
    if( getName() != null && getName().length() > 0){
        this.setDisciplineList( <working_connection_with_db_sending_getName()> );
    }else{
        this.setDisciplineList( <working_connection_with_db_all_results> );
    }   
}
```

Summarizing, I want that when user type something in input field, the disciplines list got updated with the matched disciplines - everything without page reload, when user change input field, the table is updated in real-time with the matching disciplines.

### I can do something like that?

```
<h:inputText id="discipline" value="#{disciplineMBean.name}">
    <f:ajax event="keyup" action="#{disciplineMBean.updateList}" reRender="myTable" />
</h:inputText>
```

### Edit:

I already solved my problem, but I don't know if my way is the best way to do this things. So I will leave this question open and wait a answer explainning a better way to do this (for future users that need a similar feature). When a good answer be posted, I will give this the best answer.

Note: I translated the variable names, so sorry if I forget something.

Comment: You have a tag "jsf-2" in your post. But with JSF 2 the `reRender` attribute was renamed to `render`. Do you use JSF 2?

Comment: Yes, JavaServer Faces 2.0. I must rename `reRender` to `render`?

Comment: If I change to "render" I got the following error: `<f:ajax> contains an unknown id 'myTable' - cannot locate it in the context of the component discipline`

Comment: This is because you've two forms which are [NamingContainer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html). To resolve `myTable`, set `render=":myTable"`

Comment: I change "reRender" to `render` and the value of this attribute I change from "myTable" to `:myTable`. See the edit.

Comment: @noone: `reRender` never existed in JSF 1.x, even more, the whole `<f:ajax>` didn't exist in JSF 1.x. The `reRender` attribute is recognizable from RichFaces 3.x `<a4j:xxx>` components. So actually nothing was being renamed in JSF 2.x. The whole `<f:ajax>` is brand new in JSF 2.0. All JSF 2.x books, tutorials and even tag documentation correctly shows `render` as valid attribute. The OP was just being careless by Googling/guessing around instead of simply looking in official documentation.

Comment: @BalusC oops, I knew something was incorrect when I wrote it :D

Comment: @BalusC Post as answer and I'll give you the best answer :)